# How do I notify in Android the ViewModel when a background job has finished creating a new record using LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have an application which from one activity triggers a background job using [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html). This job inserts in a database using [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) once it's done. To notify the ViewModel I'm using [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html). I have set up a main activity which uses [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) and everything is injected with [Dagger 2](https://google.github.io/dagger/).

The problem is as follows: when I launch the main activity the list is populated as expected. However when from other activity I schedule a job and said job is finished and a new record has been inserted in the database **the main activity does not update**.

Moreover, if I update a record from the main activity (without using a job) the view refreshes as expected, which makes me believe that the problem has to do with the ViewModel not detecting when a record is inserted using a job.

If I'm using LiveData, isn't it supposed to catch all the new insertions? How could I manually notify the ViewModel of the new record?

**Edit:**

Repository:

```
@Singleton
class DebtsRepository @Inject constructor(
        var debtDao: DebtDao
) {

    fun insertDebt(debt: Debt) {
        debtDao.insert(debt)
        Log.e("DebtsRepository", "debt inserted")
    }

    fun getAllDebts(): LiveData<List<Debt>> {
        return debtDao.findAll()
    }

    fun getAllDebtsWithInformation(): LiveData<List<DebtWithDebtorCreditorAndProduct>> {
        return debtDao.findAllWithProductDebtorAndCreditor()
    }

    fun payDebt(debtId: Long) {
        val paidDebt = debtDao.findOne(debtId)
        debtDao.update(paidDebt.copy(paid = true))
    }

    fun getUnpaidDebts(debts: List<DebtWithDebtorCreditorAndProduct>): List<DebtWithDebtorCreditorAndProduct> = debts.filter { !it.debt.paid }

}
```

Here is the ViewModel:

```
@Singleton
class DebtsListViewModel @Inject constructor(var debtsRepository: DebtsRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private var debts: LiveData<List<Debt>> = MutableLiveData()
    private var formattedDebts: LiveData<List<DebtWithDebtorCreditorAndProduct>> = MutableLiveData()

    init {
        debts = debtsRepository.getAllDebts()
        formattedDebts = Transformations.switchMap(debts) {
            Log.e("DebtsListViewModel", "change triggered")
            debtsRepository.getAllDebtsWithInformation()
        }
    }

    fun getFormattedDebts() = formattedDebts

    fun payDebt(debtId: Long) {
        debtsRepository.payDebt(debtId)
    }

    fun getUnpaidDebts(): List<DebtWithDebtorCreditorAndProduct> =
            if (formattedDebts.value != null)
                debtsRepository.getUnpaidDebts(formattedDebts.value!!)
            else
                emptyList()

}
```

This is the job:

```
class GenerateDebtJobService : JobService() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var debtsRepository: DebtsRepository

    @Inject
    lateinit var productDao: ProductDao

    @Inject
    lateinit var productsDebtorsDao: ProductDebtorDao

    @Inject
    lateinit var productCreditorsDao: ProductCreditorDao

    override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters): Boolean {
        DaggerGraphBuilder.build(applicationContext as FineApplication).inject(this)
        val productId = params.extras.getLong("id")
        val product = productDao.findOne(productId)
        val productCreditor = productCreditorsDao.findOneByProduct(productId)
        val debtors = productsDebtorsDao.findAllByProduct(productId)

        // When the bill day is reached for a given product the debtors list associated with that product is looped through and a new debt is created
        debtors.forEach {
            debtsRepository.insertDebt(Debt(productId = it.productProductId, debtorId = it.productDebtorId, quantity = product.recurringCost, date = DateTime().toString(), creditorId = productCreditor.productCreditorId))
        }

        return false
    }

    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters): Boolean {
        Log.e("GenerateDebtJob", "job finished")
        return false
    }

    companion object {
        fun build(application: Application, productId: Long, periodicity: Days, startDay: Days) {
            val serviceComponent = ComponentName(application, GenerateDebtJobService::class.java)
            val bundle = PersistableBundle()
            bundle.putLong("id", productId)

            val builder = JobInfo.Builder(productId.toInt(), serviceComponent)
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
//                    .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(periodicity.days.toLong()))
                    .setOverrideDeadline(1_000)
                    .setExtras(bundle)

            (application.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler).schedule(builder.build())
        }
    }

}
```

**More edits:**

I found out that the **instance of the repository on the App is different that the instance of the repository on the background job**. This makes the LiveData unable to trigger new changes when there are new records inserted in the DB.

So my guess is that somehow I have to check if the app is on the foreground and if so inject the current instance of the repository into the job.

If not, then the dependency graph must be created and as the job executes without the app running.

Here are the relevant parts of DI configuration:

AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AppModule::class,
    AndroidInjectionModule::class,
    DebtsListViewModelModule::class,
    DebtsListModule::class,
    AddProductModule::class
])
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(application: FineApplication)
    fun inject(generateDebtJobService: GenerateDebtJobService)

}
```

AppModule:

```
@Singleton
@Module
class AppModule(private val application: Application) {

    @Provides
    fun provideApplicationContext(): Context = application

    @Provides
    fun provideAppDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase =
            Room
                    .databaseBuilder<AppDatabase>(context, AppDatabase::class.java, AppDatabase.DB_NAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()

    @Provides
    fun provideDebtDao(database: AppDatabase): DebtDao = database.debtDao()

    @Provides
    fun provideDebtorDao(database: AppDatabase): DebtorDao = database.debtorDao()

    @Provides
    fun provideCreditorDao(database: AppDatabase): CreditorDao = database.creditorDao()

    @Provides
    fun provideProductDao(database: AppDatabase): ProductDao = database.productDao()

    @Provides
    fun provideProductDebtorDao(database: AppDatabase): ProductDebtorDao = database.productDebtorDao()

    @Provides
    fun provideProductCreditorDao(database: AppDatabase): ProductCreditorDao = database.productCreditorDao()

}
```

Application:

```
class FineApplication : Application(), HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingActivityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    private val component by lazy {
        DaggerAppComponent
                .builder()
                .appModule(AppModule(this))
                .build()
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        component.inject(this)
        Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this)
        JodaTimeAndroid.init(this)
    }

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> = dispatchingActivityInjector

}
```

If there is anything else needed just let me know.

Comment: Is the LiveData obtained from Room DAO, or is it manual? Do you call `postValue()` from the job on the LiveData if the Job is complete (in case your LiveData is a `MutableLiveData` you manage manually)?

Comment: The LiveData is obtained from a custom repository, which is obtained from a Room Dao. No, the Job does not have any reference to LiveData, it has injected via Dagger a repository which uses to insert the new record. Should I use MutableLiveData and call it from the job?

Comment: LiveData obtained from a `@Query` of a Room DAO should be updated when the table the query is based on is modified, so you shouldn't have to manually update it...

Comment: Yeah, it should... :/ Added the code so you can see what I've done.

Comment: Where do you observe the LiveData?

Comment: The RoomDAO has a @Query which returns LiveData. Then from the repository I access said LiveData and return it as it is. After that from the ViewModel I have a field which holds a LiveData and populates it from the repository. Finally from the activity I observe to the changes in the ViewModel's LiveData. It works when updating from the UI but not when a new record is inserted in the database from a background job.

Comment: Can you show the relevant query / dao?

Comment: Ok. I found out that the instance of the repository on the App is different that  the instance of the repository on the background job. I edited the question to reflect the new findings.